# ul hover problem with chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, hidden

I'm using this for displaying a drop down menu. It works in all browsers except Chrome:

html is:

```
   <ul id="menu">

    <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Tasks</a>
         <ul id="hiddenmenu" class="add"> // this is the hidden drop down menu
           <li> [.etc..] </li>
         </ul>
  </li>           
  </ul>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
ul#menu li ul.add {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
left: -9000px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 150px;
    }

    ul#menu li:hover ul.add, ul#menu li.sfhover ul.add {
left: -81px;
top: 4px;
*top: 12px;
    }
```

How could i make this work on chrome?

Comment: BUt it's working in chrome version 11.0.696.68

Comment: on which version you are trying?

Comment: why not use display:none when not hovering and display:block when hovering? works in all browsers

Comment: @Ahsan i'm running on 12.0.742.122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're using `-81px`, but that moves the `ul` over `81px` to the left the same way in all browsers. With that said, you should specify a `position: absolute, relative, etc` to the `CSS` styles.

Comment: also dont know why he doenst use directly display:none; and display:block;

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the issue, I am assuming he is trying to have it float off the screen on mouse out? if that is the case, toggling the `display` would be a far more efficient way of doing it, you are correct.